# Vectors, iterators and their addresses

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator

Consider the following piece of code:

```
using std::vector;

vector<vector<int>::iterator*> v;
vector<int> A{1,2,3,4};
vector<vector<int>::iterator> tmp(4);

int i=-1;
for (auto it=A.begin(); it!=A.end(); ++it) {
    tmp[++i]=it, v.push_back(&tmp[i]);
}

for (auto& x: v)
    std::cout<<**x<<" ";
```

This, when compiled with GCC 6.4.0 on MacOS 10.12.5, produces the expected output `1 2 3 4`.

But, if we modify the above code slightly, like this:

```
using std::vector;

vector<vector<int>::iterator*> v;
vector<int> A{1,2,3,4};
vector<vector<int>::iterator> tmp;

for (auto it=A.begin(); it!=A.end(); ++it) {
    tmp.push_back(it), v.push_back(&tmp.back());
}

for (auto& x: v)
    std::cout<<**x<<" ";
```

It throws `SIGSEGV`. Why does this happen? Is even the behavior of first code implementation dependent/undefined, and I was just lucky that it worked?

Comment: You can't store iterators like this because push_back invalidates all iterators when memory is reallocated. I suggest you familiarize yourself with iterator invalidation rules for the STL's various containers.

Comment: push_back invalidates iterators of the vector object on which it is being called. Not the iterators it contains.

Comment: `tmp.push_back(it), v.push_back(&tmp.back());` The iterator you store in `v` on the first iteration is likely invalidated in the second (or following) iterations by calling `push_back` on `tmp`. Its not the `push_back` on `v` that's the problem, it's the one on `tmp`. In the first version of the code no reallocation happens for `tmp` because you made it big enough to begin with.

Comment: You can fix it with `tmp.reserve(4)` at the start.

Answer (score 3):

> It throws SIGSEGV. Why does this happen?

You are storing pointers to objects in `v` that become invalid when `tmp.push_back(it)` needs to reallocate memory to be able to store the next item.

> Is even the behavior of first code implementation dependent/undefined, and I was just lucky that it worked?

The first block of code is expected to work in a predictable manner because you created a vector with the required size and did not change its size for the rest of the program. Had you used `push_back` on the vector, that block of code would also have been subject to undefined behavior.

---

As mentioned in comments, you can fix the problem in the second block of code by reserving space for the expected number of elements in the vector.

```
tmp.reserve(4);
for (auto it=A.begin(); it!=A.end(); ++it) {
    tmp.push_back(it), v.push_back(&tmp.back());
}
```

Comment: @TriskalJM, Thanks for the suggestion.